# Can I copy a VirtualBox vm from a linux machine to a Windows machine and use it?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox

Can I copy a VirtualBox vm from a linux machine to my Windows 7 machine and run it from there?

It's huge so I don't want to go through the hassle if it's not worth it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Virtualbox is on both boxes? Certainly. That's half the beauty of virtualization -- they always present the same hardware.

Answer (score 4):

YES!  Just make sure the Virtual box version is the same (or at least close)

Comment: Sorry; Chris_K barely beat you :-)